# How do I prevent soreness due to friction when swimming?

Tags: prevention, swimming

When swimming in the ocean I often get rashes where I have skin to skin contact, especially where my arms move against my torso and where my thighs move against each other. What can I do to prevent the rash short of wearing a bathing suit that covers these areas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've done several triathlons where I've had this problem. I bought BodyGlide, which is an anti-chafe stick. It works wonders and I've used it for hiking as well. Put this on there area where you typically get rashes and you'll be all set. It goes on invisible as well.

Answer (score 2):

The simple solution is not to rub your arms against your torso. If you can't do this, you can buy things like rash vests, that a lot of surfers and kayakers use, or even house fat or Vaseline like cross channel swimmers use.

Answer (score 0):

There is a product called naked surf that you can apply as a liquid rash guard.